# Convert row into concatenated string with column names included

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that is several hundred columns wide. Is there a way to convert each row into a single concatenated string with the column title included without having to list each single column in the query? I've done some of it with a query, but that is laborious to do for each column and seems error-prone. Here is a brief snippet showing three columns concatenated in the format I need, done in the column-by-column approach:

```
SELECT 
 Concat( 
   IIf(Id IS NULL, Null, Concat('Id: ' , [Id] , '\n') )  , 
   IIf(StandardClientId IS NULL, Null, 
     Concat('StandardClientId: ' , [StandardClientId] , '\n') )  , 
   IIf(ClientName IS NULL, Null, 
     Concat('ClientName: ' , [ClientName] , '\n') ) 
 )  AS ReportLine
FROM dbo.DataDecoded;
```

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Standard.

Thanks

Comment: This would be much more easily accomplished at the presentation layer.  What are you using to display this information?

Comment: You could probably do it with dynamic SQL or by building the query by querying `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`, but why wouldn't you just do this formatting in your application?  I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish.  It almost looks like you're trying to UNPIVOT the table.

Comment: I'm using this to print out reports for each selected row. Each row represents an occurrence report, and each column represents a field in the report--so people trying to understand a particular report would need to see it laid out like this.

Comment: Print it where?  Using what?  In my experience, people consuming information like this are used to spreadsheets with column headers etc. and don't need the column headers inside the data cells themselves.

Comment: Would this meet your needs? 
select * from mytable FOR JSON AUTO
 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn921882.aspx

Comment: @ScottHutchinson That's only available in SQL Server 2016, OP states they're using 2014.

Comment: @Michael McGriff: Many of the fields contain long text narratives. Others contain structured data for which the text representation may be a sentence or two. The final report reads more like a story than a spreadsheet and is actually unusable in a spreadsheet (I tried that first).

Comment: Oops, I thought FOR JSON was in SQL Server 2014. Well, maybe FOR XML then would be the next best thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to write a query that writes the annoying part of your statement for you:

```
SELECT ORDINAL_POSITION,
    COLUMN_NAME,
    CONCAT('IIF(',COLUMN_NAME,' IS NULL, NULL, CONCAT(''', COLUMN_NAME, ''', '': '',', QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME), ', ''\n'')), ')
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
    AND TABLE_NAME = 'DataDecoded'
ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION;
```

You can take it a step further and make the whole thing dynamic in an sproc, but that might be a waste of time.

Comment: Along the same lines, here's something simple you might be able to build on: 

SELECT CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME, ': ')
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Address' AND TABLE_SCHEMA='Person'
FOR XML PATH ('')